Does Looker Studio have API functionality, and if not, how else can I do this?
I'm trying to automate a workflow using Looker Studio.
Requirements are very simple - I need to be able to programmatically copy a templated report (from a Python/Java application) and import/set a data source (Google Sheets doc) for that report. Nothing else.
My problem is I cannot find where to get the the Looker studio API credentials.
The only directly related posts I can find reference the Looker tool and not the Looker Studio tool.
I tried reading multiple articles on google and couldn't find anything.

This question is similar to: Does Google Data Studio have API functionality, and if not, will it in the near future?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Build a connector using: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/connector/build. Set authentication type in getAuthType().

I found great success using the Looker Studio Linking API. https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/linking-api

Get the report ID of your template file. Also note the datasource alias you use in your template. This is easily found in the URL: https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/<YOUR_REPORTING_ID>/
Then in your python construct a link in this format: https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/create?c.reportId=<YOUR_REPORTING_ID>&ds.<YOUR_DATASOURCE_ALIAS>.connector=googleSheets &ds.<YOUR_DATASOURCE_ALIAS>.spreadsheetId=<YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID> &ds.<YOUR_DATASOURCE_ALIAS>.worksheetId=<YOUR_WORKSHEET_ID>
There are a host of additional url params should you want additional configuration such as customizing the report name.

