Does Google Looker Studio/Data Studio provides programatic access? and what's differece between Looker and Looker Studio?
I have a use case where I want to share reports with specific template-id ideally for my different Big Query tables, each tables contain different data but in the same schema, and want to share these tables with different emails.
import { google } from 'googleapis';

const datastudio = google.datastudio({ // error: datastudio does not exist
  version: 'v1',
  auth,
});

I am using TypeScript SDK googleapis and then tried to get autocompletion for Data Studio I couldn't get this type here: google.datastudio.
I saw there is autocompletion for looker but looks like Looker Studio and Looker are different things? correct me if I am wrong. I saw the discussion here: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Looker-Studio/Looker-vs-Looker-Studio/m-p/589985
I also want to understand what is the actual difference between Looker and Looker Studio since here it's docs say it's core APIs: https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/reference/rest So my question is can we use Looker to interact with all kind of resources or what? like Big Query and even Looker Studio?
Also please let me know if Looker Studio SDK doesn't exist then can we create the report using some kind of programmatic access or not?
Update:
Ok seems like there is some API endpoint but maybe not the ability to create a report by pointing out Big Query table using some kind of programming language?: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/api

Needs to close this question since found a discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259447/does-google-data-studio-have-api-functionality-and-if-not-will-it-in-the-near
and I am concluding that API doesn't exist, while closing can't find the above question in duplicate so if someone can help close then thanks.

One more discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78674327/does-looker-studio-have-api-functionality-and-if-not-how-else-can-i-do-this
